# Get Installed win32 application

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp

Is there any way to get installed win32 applications in UWP project?(since in uwp project I am unable to add reference of wmi call and registry).If so how it is achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

Classical win32 application can get installed win32 applications on the device by reading the registry. But in a store app, in short answer, it cannot. A store app runs in an isolated sandbox and cannot read the system level registry. For details reasons about why store app doesn't support access the registry please reference [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/01741dca-34cf-4fae-816b-832bc49bc906/how-can-a-windows-store-app-read-from-and-write-to-the-registry?forum=winappswithnativecode).

However, if you don't want upload your app to windows store, you can try out the Brokered Windows Runtime Components for side-loaded Windows Store apps. Essentially, it allows you UWP app to call Win32 API hosted in a different process, which runs outside of the App container.

For brokered WinRT component template for VS2015 you can download [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d2e9cac0-66a8-464a-a902-55ae765c8e6e?tduid=(c5f2776eb12ea55b8926d0c075062c9d)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-gN1OuW5VyKxMyOTAH.bK0w)()).

For more details and sample about Brokered Windows Runtime Components please reference [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-515) and [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn630195.aspx).

Comment: Is there any way to get installed uwp application in the system? I tried with PackageManager class bt it does not works.Is there some other way?.I dont want to use powershell.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get installed uwp application in the system? I tried with PackageManager class bt it does not works.Is there some other way?.I dont want to use powershell.

For getting installed store apps, I have tested [PackageManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.aspx) class on my side. It did work well and as far as I know it is the best way to got installed store apps. Code as follows:

```
var packageManager = new PackageManager();
IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package> packages = (IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package>)packageManager.FindPackagesForUser("");
var list = packages.ToList();
```

Pay attention that these code running on uwp require `packageManagement`  restricted capability. More details about special and restricted capabilities [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#special-and-restricted-capabilities). And your app cannot be uploaded to windows store.

For using this code in traditional Win32 project just referernce the sample in [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.aspx).