# Adding a additional context menu to windows 10 phone

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

How to add context menu to windows phone 10's context menu.

Menu will get added when app is install & run for first time.

Clicking on that menu will open the app with provided data.

Is it possible in UWP ?

[Context Menu in Edge mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjkSH.png)
[Context Menu in Edge mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPuW1.png)

Comment: Are you referring to the context menu that is displayed when you tap and hold on an app in the app list? Jump lists aren't supported on mobile.

Comment: What `context menu` you actually mean here? Could you please provide a   picture to describe more clearly? Did you mean add a menu on start screen like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2dH9.png) showed?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Post updated with image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to add context menu to windows phone 10's context menu.

Actually every app in windows phone 10 has its own default `context menu`. Not all the app have the same context menu called 'windows phone 10 context menu'. For example, the people app's default context menus are "Edit","Delete" and so on, and the photo app's are "Share","Add to album" and so on. So you need to determine which app's context menu you need to added.

If you want add context menu for a uwp app you're developing, that is easy to do. In uwp app you can use [`PopupMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208693) to create a custom context menu and with [`UICommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242166) to add menu items. Details please reference the context menu [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/ContextMenu). If you want to launch another app by selecting one item, you need to launch the app by [Launcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241801) class when the item selected. More details about how to launch an app please reference [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/AssociationLaunching).

If you want add context menu for Edge app as the picture you showed, you need to use the [Microsoft Edge Extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/). That extension support context menu relative APIs like `contextMenus.create` method. Details please reference the  [supported APIs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/api-support/supported-apis/) in the extension. Pay attention that the context menu APIs for Edge only support for Microsoft Edge (38) / Windows 10 (14393).

Same for other apps, if the app doesn't open an extension or public APIs, you cannot change the contextMenu directly.

> Menu will get added when app is install & run for first time.

You cannot add a menu to another app when current app is first run since the uwp app is sandbox. For third party apps like Edge, you can only complete the extension and load it to explorer to let the context menu changes take effects, you cannot control it from your app.

Comment: Thanks for very detail answer.  Can UWP app install extension on Edge ? (I know currently Edge is not supporting extension, but it would be handy in future). For example, Windows Application can add additional context menu to Windows Right Click.

Comment: @AbhijeetSuryawanshi, edge supporting extension, you can reference this [document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/guides/adding-and-removing-extensions/). UWP cannot install extension on Edge. If you want to use win32 APIs in uwp you can reference [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156998/get-installed-win32-application/41220711#41220711). If my reply helped you , thanks for mark as accepted.